# How to calculate standard deviation from mean and probability?

Tags: standard-deviation

What's the formula to calculate the standard deviation **knowing** the mean and a certain probability, but **not knowing** all the n's.

http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/normal.aspx

For example, ^that calculator only requires mean and a probability of Z to calculate the mean... so how does it do that? What's the formula? And how can I do it by myself in a CAS software during an exam?

Comment: This the normal distribution and it has a known probability function and a standard table, it is a different case.

Answer (score -1):

The formula for standard deviation is sqrt([sample size]*[probability of success]*(1-[probability of success])). To find the sample size from the mean and success rate, you divide the mean by the success rate. If mean=10 and success=0.2, you do 10/0.2 to get your sample size, or 50 in this case. Then you do sqrt(50*0.2*(1-0.2) to get about 2.83. There you go!